# solution to non linear recurrence relation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

> I have the following recurrence relation $y_{j+1}=y_j-\frac{2}{3}\alpha h (y_j)^{\frac{3}{2}}$ where $\alpha, h$ are constants and $y_0$ is some constant as well.

I do know how to solve linear reccurence relations but I dont have any idea how to go about this one.
Would appreciate a tipp/help

Comment: What are you trying to solve?

Comment: Trying to solve the recurrence relation given above.

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"?

Comment: Finding an explicit formula for the sequence $y_j$ (not using $y_i$ $i<j$)